# Ler arquivos de forma síncrona no Cordova

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, sistema-de-arquivos

Existe alguma forma de, no Apache Cordova, ler o conteúdo de um arquivo e salvar em uma variável de forma síncrona?

Isto porque, [na API de Arquivos do Cordova você deve usar uma função de callback ao ler um arquivo para obter o resultado](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#read-a-file), e acaba sendo de certa forma um pouco inconveniente, ficar dividindo o código dentro de callbacks.

Então, teria alguma forma de ler um conteúdo do arquivo e salvar o resultado em uma variável, sem precisar de um callback?

---

**Método com callbacks de exemplo do Apache Cordova:**

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
    fs.root.getFile("arquivo.txt", { create: false, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function() {
                console.log("Conteúdo do Arquivo: " + this.result);
            };

            reader.readAsText(file);
        }, onErrorReadFile);
    }, onErrorLoadFile);
}, onErrorLoadFs);
```

---

**Método desejado, sem callbacks:** (exemplo)

```
var texto = funcaoSincronaDeLerArquivo("arquivo.txt")

// manipulação do conteúdo, somente exemplo
if (texto == "admin") {
    window.location = "admin.html";
} else {
    window.location = "user.html";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devido a natureza do Cordova, um framework que trabalha fazendo a mediação da comunicação do seu código com o aparelho em linguagem nativa, dificilmente você terá essa possibilidade, pois o próprio Cordova faz uma chamada assíncrona na linguagem nativa e aguarda resultado para passar para o callback que você define.

Você pode usar `Promise` para tornar o controle mais simples e o código mais limpo.

Usando callbacks seu código vai criando uma pirâmide e o chamado *callback hell*:

```
asyncFunc1(false, function(ret1){
    asyncFunc2(false, function(ret2){
        asyncFunc3(false, function(ret3){
            console.log(ret3);
        }, genericErrorHandler);
    }, genericErrorHandler);
}, genericErrorHandler);
```

Com *promises* você lineariza isso, tornando mais simples de ler e controlar:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    asyncFunc1(false, resolve, reject);
}).then (function(ret1) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        asyncFunc2(false, resolve, reject);
    });
}).then (function(ret2){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        asyncFunc3(false, resolve, reject);
    });
}).then(function(ret3) {
    console.log(ret3);
}, genericErrorHandler);
```

Por exemplo, capturar uma imagem da câmera com callbacks

```
function getPictureWithoutPromises(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imagePath) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imagePath, function (imageFileEntry) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function (appDataDirEntry) {
                imageFileEntry.copyTo(appDataDirEntry, null, function (newImageFileEntry) {
                    successCallback(newImageFileEntry);
                }, errorCallback);
            }, errorCallback);
        }, errorCallback);
    }, errorCallback);
}

getPictureWithoutPromises(function (imageFileEntry) {
    image.src = imageFileEntry.toURL();
}, function (err) {
    console.log("Error : ", err);
});
```

E capturar a imagem da câmera usando `Promise`

```
function getPictureWithPromises() {
    var sourceImageFileEntry;

    return new Promise(function (returnResolve, returnReject) {
        new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(resolve, reject);
        }).then(function (imagePath) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imagePath, resolve, reject);
            });
        }).then(function (imageFileEntry) {
            sourceImageFileEntry = imageFileEntry;
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, resolve, reject);
            });
        }).then(function (appDataDirEntry) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                sourceImageFileEntry.copyTo(appDataDirEntry, null, resolve, reject);
            });
        }).then(function (newImageFileEntry) {
                returnResolve(newImageFileEntry)
        });
    });
}

getPictureWithPromises().then(function (imageFileEntry) {
    image.src = imageFileEntry.toURL();
}, function (err) {
    console.log("Error : ", err);
});
```

Você pode usar a biblioteca [cordova-promise-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-promise-fs) pra utilizar as funções do sistema de arquivos do cordova com promessas ou estudá-las para implementar no seu código, caso não atenda suas necessidades. Mas infelizmente não há como fazer este procedimento sem uma abordagem assíncrona.